# Java and ITA2 charset

Tags: java, character-encoding

Anyone who has experience with encoding messages using the ITA2 charset?

I am wondering if there exists some Java library supporting this, or if I would have to implement everything from scratch?

ITA2 on wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baudot_code#ITA2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague of mine found the following repo containing Java code doing ITA2 encoding and decoding on GitHub:
https://github.com/TonyWhite/Baudot

It has some bugs and limitations (and it is in italian), but with a couple of modifications I made it work for my purposes.